# AngularJS: Pass binding in ng-click directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've called a function on the `ng-click` event from my html but would like to pass the output of an `ng-repeat` as a parameter to that function. INthis case `{{item.url}}` is the output of the `ng-repeat`.

```
ng-click = "urlSetter({{item.url}})"
```

Within the `Controller` of the page I have created the relevent function and set it in the `$scope`.

```
$scope.urlSetter = function(url){
        console.log(url);
    };
```

How can I pass the binding to the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use interpolation (`{{}}`) inside `ng-click` directive.

```
ng-click = "urlSetter(item.url)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are iterating through the list of `items` here is how you do it.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="urlSetter(item.url)"></div>
```

The usage `{{item.url}}` is used inside the HTML elements to output the bound valueof `item.url` onto the HTML. But when you pass it to a controller method you can just use the variable name